# Python packaging: how to handle extras?

Tags: python, pip

I have a networking python project which does not require a monitoring system to function. However, we added to the code a way to communicate data to different monitoring systems using clients from those monitoring systems.

Right now, in requirements.txt I have a dependency per potential client and when I install the project (pip setup.py install) all get installed. Nevertheless, I wonder if it would be possible to package the project in a way that when installing it, I can specify the client I want to use (or none) and then dependencies get installed accordingly.

For example, having an extra argument which specifies the monitoring system

```
python setup.py install monitor_system_1
```

And something in requirements.txt which does this logic:

```
SomeProject >=1.2
OtherProject == 4.0
if monitor_system_1 in xxxx:
    monitor_system_1_client
if monitor_system_2 in xxxx:
    monitor_system_2_client
```

Comment: `requirements.txt` doesn't have any 'extras' or conditionals support. Also, `setup.py` doesn't normally work with `requirements.txt`, that's a file aimed at local `pip` use. A client installing your project would typically install a wheel or compressed archive with the source code (`.tgz`, `.zip`), and then the metadata recorded in the wheel or set in the `setup.py` script is used. *Those* have explicit `extras` support. Presumably your `setup.py` reads the `requirements.txt` file to define dependencies? Can you show us in your question how they integrate?

Comment: You are right! The project is installed through pip. Do you have more info about how to use `extras` in requirements.txt? and how those extras can be used when installing the package through pip? I found this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#extras but it does not say how to tell pip that it should install the extras: security.

Comment: You can't use `extras` *in the `requirements.txt` file*, no. You can define additional files, perhaps, but I'd first like to see how your `setup.py` file is set up.

Comment: See https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras for the documentation on how extras work in `setup.py`.